# JSoup scraping - attempting to scrape data from 70 pages at once but my loop isn't working

Tags: java, for-loop, jsoup

I am attempting to scrape house information from an [accommodation website](http://www.myhome.ie/rentals/dublin/property-to-rent). After each house I want to print the address and price (later i will insert into a databse) and move onto the next house but it is not doing that. It is printing each house, but doing it 6 or 7 times each.

Here is my code:

```
int j = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<67; i++) {
        String link = "http://www.myhome.ie/rentals/dublin/property-to-rent?page=" + j;
        Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        Elements addresses = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .address a");
        Elements prices = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .descriptionTitle .price");
        for (Element address : addresses) {
            for (Element price : prices) {
                System.out.println(address.text());
                System.out.println(price.text());
            }
            j=j+1;
        }

    }
```

My output keeps printing like this:

```
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€4,250 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€17,500 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€5,500 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€2,750 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€3,200 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€19,500 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€1,300 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€1,500 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€2,000 / month
Radcliffe Hall, St Johns Road, Sandymount, Dublin 4
€2,300 / month
```

Comment: Try moving the `j = j+1` line out of the loop and add it as the last statement of the outermost loop.

Comment: @turingcomplete No, unfortunately that still has the same problem. The address and price elements are printing multiple times.

Comment: maybe you should print the address in the first loop, and not inside the nested for loop?

Comment: @asgs I had tried that before but it prints out the address once but then prints the price 7 times each.

Comment: actually, it's not clear what the mapping between addresses and prices is. is it one to one? In that case, you don't need two for loops. Just use one and print the address and its price in one go.

Comment: @asgs I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not using any database here. The reason I'm using two JSoup elements is because I've to scrape two different parts of the HTML, but I'd like to have them both show up together so I can identify which house it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to send 67 get requests, but you're using the `j` index here:

`String link = "http://www.myhome.ie/rentals/dublin/property-to-rent?page=" + j;`

That should be `i` to fix the first part of your problem. Then, assuming a 1-to-1 mapping of price and address, you only need a single inner loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 67; i++) {
    String link = "http://www.myhome.ie/rentals/dublin/property-to-rent?page=" + i;
    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
    Elements addresses = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .address a");
    Elements prices = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .descriptionTitle .price");

    //assumes a 1-to-1 address-price mapping
    for(int j = 0; j < addresses.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(addresses.get(j).text());
        System.out.println(prices.get(j).text());
    }
}
```

Comment: This has helped a lot. Knew it would be something small. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This code should give the correct output. Only one inner loop is needed, not nested loops.

```
int j = 1;

for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
    String link = "http://www.myhome.ie/rentals/dublin/property-to-rent?page=" + j;
    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
    Elements addresses = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .address a");
    Elements prices = doc2.select("#results #resultItem .descriptionTitle .price");
    for (int k = 0; k < addresses.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(addresses.get(k).text());
        System.out.println(prices.get(k).text());
    }
        j=j+1;
    }
```

Output:

```
5 Luttrell Park Close, Carpenterstown,, Castleknock, Dublin 15
€1,800 / month
littlepace Woods, Clonee, Dublin 15
€1,500 / month
371 Grace Park Heights, Drumcondra, Dublin 9
€1,800 / month
44 cherbury court, Booterstown, County Dublin
€1,400 / month
The Saddlers, Blanchardstown, Dublin 15
€1,475 / month
```